# How to do user-control validation to require at least one input?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html

[image: Dialog to Upload a File or Specify a Link]

I am learning ASP.NET and have a problem, which I would appreciate some help overcoming.

in the above picture I want a user to upload a file or provide a link.

Could anyone tell how to validation on this?

Comment: http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/required-field-validator/

Comment: Dear Dr. Stitch, i want a user to upload a file or provide a link. He has to do one of two things. How to do that.

Comment: try using custom validator. http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/custom-validator/ put your logic inside the servervalidate event.